# Deep inside jackson - how can I get the property name from a getter

Tags: java, jackson

I am digging on Jackson 2 and I want to know where and how the getter-method name gets converted into a property name.

I have tried:

```
PropertyName foo = new PropertyName("getKarli");
System.out.println(foo.getSimpleName());
```

I and I have found BeanProperty.Std() but this one have a lot of wired constructors. The api is bigger then expected :-) Is there a Jackson class and method where I can just pass the method and get back the correct property text used in the json?

EDIT:

I have also tried this one but that gives me a NullPointer

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.Annotated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethod;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BeanPropertyDefinition;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

public class Test {
    public String getKarli() {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {

        node.remove("geheim");
        System.out.println(node.toString());

        Annotated aa = new AnnotatedMethod(Test.class.getMethod("getKarli"), null, null);
        System.out.println(
                new ObjectMapper().getSerializationConfig().getAnnotationIntrospector().findNameForSerialization(aa)
        );
        // new BeanProperty.Std()
    }
}
```

Comment: can u elaborate more on what is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: I really just want to get the property name from the getter. And I need to match the json property with that name - so I need the exact same name. To get the exact same name the best ist to use the same method as jackson does, I think

Comment: where is propertyName class from?

Comment: @PaulJohn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyName

Answer (score 0):

Found it.

```
String name = BeanUtil.okNameForRegularGetter(p, p.getName(), true);
if(name == null) name = BeanUtil.okNameForIsGetter(p, p.getName(), true);
```